# VBA Excel: Using SaveAs Dialog for Text Files/Custom File Types

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel macro which writes a specific string to a text file. The catch is, I need to save it as a custom file (".us1"). I'm attaching my current code below. I ended up doing a weird reversal of the Open dialog. What would I do to switch this code to using the SaveAs Dialog?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim stream As TextStream
Dim FilePath As String
Dim ofD As Object
CommandButton2.Height = 53.25
CommandButton2.Width = 83.25
CommandButton2.Left = 222.75
CommandButton2.Top = 508.5

If OptionButton5.Value = True Then

    MsgBox "NOTE! This is a bi-phasic script. Every other bit, starting with the first, is a sign bit!!! DISREGARD the graph!!!"

    Set ofD = Application.FileDialog(3)
    ofD.AllowMultiSelect = False

    If ofD.Show = False Then
        MsgBox "Script Generation Canceled"
    Else
        FilePath = ofD.SelectedItems(1)
        Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile(FilePath, ForWriting, True)

        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FA 12 // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FB " + Cells(27, 2) + " // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FC 00 // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 25 00 31 FF " + Cells(33, 2) + "// "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FA 13 // "

        stream.Close
    End If
Else
    Set ofD = Application.FileDialog(3)

    ofD.AllowMultiSelect = False

    If ofD.Show = False Then
        MsgBox "Script Generation Canceled"
    Else
        FilePath = ofD.SelectedItems(1)
        Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile(FilePath, ForWriting, True)

        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FA 10 // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FB " + Cells(27, 2) + " // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FC 00 // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 25 00 31 FF " + Cells(33, 2) + "// "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FA 11 // "

        stream.Close
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're writing directly to the textstream I don't think you *need* to do any "SaveAs" (that pertains to *workbook files* that are opened in/from Excel.  So the method you have is overwriting the existing file. If you need to save it to a different file, use the `fso.CreateTextFile` method, then you can write to the new file.

Comment: @DavidZemens I get that but the whole point is giving the user the ability to select/create which ever file they want. Also, it can't be a text file...I need the SaveAs Dialog so I can apply the custom type filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by selecting the file path THROUGH the saveAs dialog. I surprisingly had no issues with the file filter.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim stream As TextStream
Dim FilePath As String
Dim saveDialog As Variant
CommandButton2.Height = 53.25
CommandButton2.Width = 83.25
CommandButton2.Left = 222.75
CommandButton2.Top = 508.5

If OptionButton5.Value = True Then

    MsgBox "NOTE! This is a bi-phasic script. Every other bit, starting with the first, is a sign bit!!! DISREGARD the graph!!!"

    saveDialog = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Script Files(*.us1), *.us1")

        Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile(saveDialog, ForWriting, True)

        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FA 12 // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FB " + Cells(27, 2) + " // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FC 00 // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 25 00 31 FF " + Cells(33, 2) + "// "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FA 13 // "

        stream.Close

Else
    saveDialog = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Script Files(*.us1),*.us1")

        Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile(saveDialog, ForWriting, True)

        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FA 10 // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FB " + Cells(27, 2) + " // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FC 00 // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 25 00 31 FF " + Cells(33, 2) + "// "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FA 11 // "

        stream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Good work. You could use `FileDialog(2)` which is the "Save As" dialog, but I think this solution using `GetSaveAsFileName` is easier.

Comment: @DavidZemens thanks! Would using `FileDialog(2)` make the code any simpler? (cleaner?)

Comment: Try it and decide for yourself which is cleaner or easier for you :)