# VBA Save as custom file

Tags: vba, excel, file, save-as

I've been trying to save some excel data as a custom text file format. By following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083325/vba-excel-using-saveas-dialog-for-text-files-custom-file-types) I didn't got too far. Excel throws Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. Any ideas why this happens?

The error happens on third line:

Set dialog = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Custom file, *.custom")

```
Sub SaveCustomData()
    Dim dialog As Variant
    Set dialog = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Custom file, *.custom")
    ' !!! The code runs this far !!!

    With dialog
        .InitialFileName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        Dim file As String
        Dim fso As FileSystemObject
        Set fso = New FileSystemObject
        Dim fileStream As TextStream

        If .Show = True Then
            file = .SelectedItems(1)

            Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(dialog, ForWriting, True)

            ' Writing data to file here

            fileStream.Close

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: can you tell us *where the error is happening* please

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code is working as intended. The `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` method returns as `False` if it's canceled, as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-getsaveasfilename-method-excel) - hence producing the Type mismatch error (you can't open a boolean). Just create a simple `if` condition that handles this behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` returns the name of the selected file (or `False` if user cancelled the dialog). You cannot (and you don't want) to assign this to your `dialog` variable

The *question* of the post you are referencing uses `Application.FileDialog(3)` (the 3 should be replaced by the constant `msoFileDialogFilePicker`), this returns a `Dialog` - this is how the rest of your code is build.

However, in the *answer* of the post, `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` is used. As this command is using the folder of the actual sheet as starting folder and doesn't allow multi select, your code can be reduced to

```
Sub SaveCustomData()
    Dim fileName As Variant
    fileName  = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Custom file, *.custom")
    if fileName = False then 
        MsgBox "No filename selected, data not saved"
        exit sub
    end if

    Dim file As String
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim fileStream As TextStream

    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName, ForWriting, True)
    ...
End Sub
```